# Manifold with corners, without its corners

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm working on Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Problem 16-8:

*Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with corners, and let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the set of corner points of $M$. Show that $M \setminus \mathcal{C}$ is a smooth manifold with boundary*.

I know that from the topological point of view, manifolds with corners and manifolds with boundaries are the same thing but I can't understand why this (the problem) has to be proven.

In a manifold with corners we also have **boundary charts**, ¿do these work for boundary charts looking at $M$ as a manifold with boundary?

¿Does the boundary need to be non-empty?

Any idea to solve the problem is useful.

Comment: you only need to check that for every point of $M\setminus C$ there is a neighborhood that is diffeomorphic to a neighborhood of $\{(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_n\geqslant 0\}$

Comment: I think I have a (good) idea. If $p$ is a corner point of $M$ then there exists a chart with corners $(U,\varphi)$ with $U$ diffeomorphic to an open set of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^n_{+}$, so $x_i (p) \geq 0$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then such chart can be taken as a boundary chart for any other $q \in U$ because $x_1(q),...,x_n(q) \geq 0$, in particular $x_n (q) \geq 0$. Is this correct?